# Trouble using jQuery & deviceready with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

This might seem like a duplicate question , but the fact is I have tried several syntax available on stack & other sites but to no avail.

I am developing my first app in PhoneGap. Initially, I used document.ready which worked great in browser. Later I found out it doesn't work in app & that I needed to use deviceready.

Thing is I have tried several syntax for that from docs & stack but all of them failed.

Also , lemme know if I need to use any plugin for using deviceready.

Testing bits of my code showed that neither deviceready event listener nor any jQuery code are working in my app. I don't know why?

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    ...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="www/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script src="www/js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.js :

```
alert('Entered JS') ;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

$(document).ready(function () {

    function onDeviceReady() {

        alert ('Device Ready') ;
        //this one is not showing

    };
});
```

This is my latest trial.

Thanks to all for helping me. The solution of the problem is as below :

1 -> Do not load any css , js or other files using URL as phoneGap or Cordova don't allow this by default.
2 -> Though if your app requires you to send requests over web, whitelist your urls using cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin of Cordova.
3 -> As of the codes, it goes as below :

index.html :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
<script src="www/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="www/js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    <!-- Loading js containing deviceready & other functions-->
    <script src="www/js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
```

As can be seen, it is necessary to include cordova.js.

index.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.isphone = false;
    if(document.URL.indexOf("http://") === -1 
        && document.URL.indexOf("https://") === -1) {
        window.isphone = true;
    }

    if( window.isphone ) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    } else {
        onDeviceReady();
    }
});

function onDeviceReady ()
{
    //...
}
```

The above code ensures your app to work on both web & devices without any changes. If you want only device based .js , then use simply :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady () { ... } ;
```

Comment: Are you including `cordova.js` script in your index.html? You need it for `deviceready` event. Therefore,it is important to import it in your head, in order to avoid weird issues related to the order in which each script is loaded.

Comment: That was one of the problems in my code. I have found a solution & will update it asap. Thanks to all...

Answer (score 0):

I use require js to load file. code as follows

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['index.js'], function () {

    });
</script>
```

index.js

```
var MobileApp = function() {
    /*Constructor for Mobile App*/
}


MobileApp.prototype = {
    w_deviceId: 0, 
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        // your code goes here
    },
}

var w_app = new MobileApp();
w_app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You do it in the wrong order, first call the jQuery-ready-event and then the cordova-ready-event:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady(){
       // start your app here.
}
```

Comment: Do i need to include cordova.js?

Comment: Is it fine if I write event dependent jquery code in onDeviceReady like .keypress & others